# How do I configure the concurrency of node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to configure the maximum capacity of Node.js? For example, say, I have 5 URLs, but with limited hardware resource, I only want to process 2 at a time. Is there an option that I can set in Node.js, such that I don't need to control it in my code?

**urls.txt**

```
https://example.com/1
https://example.com/2
https://example.com/3
https://example.com/4
https://example.com/5
```

**index.js**

```js
const readline = require('readline')
const fs = require('fs')

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('urls.txt')
})

rl.on('line', (input) => {
  console.log(`Do something with: ${input}`);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an option that I can set in Node.js, such that I don't need to control it in my code?

Nope.  That's what your code is for.

Alternatively, let the kernel handle it, since you're concerned about system resources.